# Google Maps API twice error due to two modules

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, npm, module, react-google-maps

I am using [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps) along with [location-autocomplete](https://github.com/jmsardina/location-autocomplete) in a react app.

On page load, I receive the infamous:

> "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page.
>   This may cause unexpected errors."

To repeat, I am using maps via modules and not by directly including `<script>` tags.
What is the best way to overcome such cases?

I have found this [issue](https://github.com/Charmatzis/react-leaflet-google/issues/6) on github which seems to be the same case, with different libraries but they get too deep into the specifics of their library ('leaflet'). I wonder if there is a more generic solution.

Comment: i am facing the same problem. have you solved it?

Comment: i have. But i donT really remember how. :( It might have sth to do with the 'withScripts()' though. Do you use it or not? Taking that out might have solved my issue.  https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/812

Comment: Thanks for your info. i discover this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442761/you-have-included-the-google-maps-javascript-api-multiple-times-on-this-page-th
so far haven't seen any problem yet. will let you know if i hit wall ...

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{ YOUR CODE }}&libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

To the head in the public > index.html file

and from the file where you are running the `<GoogleMap>` component remove the `<LoadScript>` wrapper because if the parent component refreshes it might cause a double instance of the Maps script