# You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors. when called using $.getScript()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Prelog: 
I have implemented Google maps and Geolocation as a independent widgets, Now the user have the ability to add the widget as much as he wants in a page he is owns.
I am using $.getScript(URl, callback) to load the script for that URL to work.

Problem : 
When the user add both the widgets or the same widget multiple times in a same page , the check windows.google fails and the $.getScript(url, callback) gets executed twice. Due to which I get an error from the Google Script

> You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on
>   this page. This may cause unexpected errors. when called using
>   $.getScript()

```
if(window.google !== undefined && window.google !== null) {
    onScriptLoad(null, null, 200);
} else {
    $.getScript(googleUrl, onScriptLoad);
}
```

The above line exists in both the widget and both the widgets are independent of each other. It always goes into the else block of both the functions.
Looking forward for some work around here, like to load the script synchronously using javascript or jquery

Comment: Please include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows to reproduce the issue **in the question itself** (or in a fiddle). With the code you posted, we can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when your code runs in the first *widget*, it initiates the loading of the google API, however `window.google` isn't created until the script completes loading. This is **asynchronous**

Now, the second *widget* tests if `window.google` exists, but this is still happening before the google API loads, therefore, it too thinks it needs to load google API

so, instead of this:

```
if(window.google !== undefined && window.google !== null) {
    onScriptLoad(null, null, 200);
} else {
    $.getScript(googleUrl, onScriptLoad);
}
```

try

```
window.loadingGoogleApi = window.loadingGoogleApi || $.getScript(googleUrl);
window.loadingGoogleApi.then(onScriptLoad);
```

the `loadingGoogleApi` can be **any** name you choose (just don't use something that will be clobbered by other code)

Comment: That is... if you are calling the posted code twice before the first `getScript` has finished loading it. We don't really know that from the question though.

Comment: @MrUpsidown - we can assume with 99% confidence that is the case :p - ok, not we, but I assumed that - the only code shown is flawed for the reasons I gave in the answer